# displaying html table row based on XSL if condition, getting error in the <xsl:if> "Tag missing closing bracket '>'"

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am attempting to conditionally display a table row. Below is my attempt to display the row once the condition is satisfied.

```
<xsl:if test= <xsl:value-of select="show_discount" /> = 'Y' >
    <tr style="font-size:9px">
        <td width="40mm" style=" text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" >
            Extra Line Discount: <xsl:value-of select="Discount" /> % = <xsl:value-of select="DiscountValue" />
        </td>
</xsl:if>
```

But, it's not working, I receive a compile error.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show your actual compile error, as error messages usually have useful descriptions. Having said that, the answer will probably be your xsl:if statement should just be `<xsl:if test="show_discount = 'Y'">`

Comment: Thanks Tim C., its working now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving a compile error because the opening `<tr>` tag does not have a closing tag in the same scope, and also because your conditional statement is malformed.

The solution:

```
<xsl:if test="show_discount = 'Y'>
    <tr style="font-size:9px">
        <td width="40mm" style=" text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
            Extra Line Discount: <xsl:value-of select="Discount" /> % = <xsl:value-of select="DiscountValue" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:if>
```